# Can I automatically populate LastUpdated fields in MongoDB (using C# driver)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, nosql

I want to automatically update a LastUpdatedOn field on a mongo document every time a save or update operation occurs on that document.

Rather than putting this burden on every bit of code that does a save/update, is there some way to automatically do this (I'm using the C# driver).

For e.g. in nHibernate you can use [interceptors](http://elegantcode.com/2008/05/15/implementing-nhibernate-interceptors/). Is there a similar technique available at either the database or driver level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> interceptors. Is there a similar technique available at either the database or
>   driver level?

There is no such mechanism in mongodb c# driver and in the mongodb as well. 
To achieve your needs you can simple wrap all `Save`, `Insert`, atomic `Update` methods and set `LastUpdatedOn` field there.

For example you can have base class for your repository, service, whatever where you will wrap your Save methods:

```
public abstract class BaseMongoService<T> where T : BaseDocument
{
   protected abstract MongoCollection Items { get; }

   public virtual SafeModeResult Save(T document)
   {
      document.LastUpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;

      return Items.Save(document);
   }
   public virtual void Update(IMongoQuery query, IMongoUpdate update)
   {
      update = update.Set("LastUpdatedOn", DateTime.Now);
      Items.Update(query, update);
   }
}
```

then you will need inherit all your documents from `BaseDocument` (or force them implement some interface) to add constraint that all documents should contains LastUpdatedOn field.

```
public class BaseDocument
{
  public DateTime LastUpdatedOn {get;set;}
}
```

Then just inherit all data access classes from above one and use Save, Update methods from base class.

***Note**: all this code was not tested, it just how i see it can be done.*

Answer (score 1):

You can populate date fields server side (inside mongo) in the following manner with **CurrentDate**:

```
public async Task UpdateAsync(YourDocument document)
{
  var updateOptions = new UpdateOptions
  {
    IsUpsert = true
  };

  var update = Builders<YourDocument>.Update
    .Set(c => c.Title, document.Title)
    .CurrentDate(c => c.LastUpdated);

  await Collection.UpdateOneAsync(c => c.Id == document.Id, update, updateOptions);
}
```

```
public record YourDocument
{
  [BsonId]
  [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
  public string Id { get; set; }

  public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

  public string Title { get; set; }
}
```